# ssrs/ssrb end user picks a date to filter by

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm using sql server 2008 r2 and i'm new to building reports with ssrs. I have the reports built, but i'm trying to make it so when the end user, goes to the report on the site, they are able to pick a start and end date. So the data gets filtered by those, to look at it each quarter.

I've been looking through the interwebs for a few hours and it looks like people are able to do this, but i haven't seen anything on how yet.

Also i see there is a date picker thats greyed out, but I've read that it can only be used in web projects, is that what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have 2008 but in 2012 you would simply define 2 parameters as date/time and amend your dataset to include them. For example

```
SELECT        SalesOrderID, OrderDate, Status, TotalDue
FROM            Sales.SalesOrderHeader
where   orderdate between @lodate and @hidate
```

The datasource in this case is advicentureworks2012.

SSRS automatically adds the parameters to the report and includes a date picker.